# Run a function every time any function in object is called

Tags: javascript

if I have an object that looks like this:

```
var animal = { 
    cat: function() { alert('woof'); },
    dog: function() { alert('meow'); }
}
```

How can I 'attach' another function to `animal` so that it runs if any function within the `animal` object is called? ( without manually calling it in each routine )

Comment: The only thing you could do now is iterate over each function property and wrap them in a new function which also calls the other function. For the future, ES6 defines "proxy objects" you might be able to use... some day. (http://wiki.ecmascript.org/doku.php?id=harmony:proxies).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
for (var p in animal) {
    if (typeof animal[p] === "function") {
        animal[p] = make(animal[p]);
    }
}

function make(fn) {
    return function() {
        console.log("this is called for every animal");
        // call the original
        return fn.apply(this, arguments);
    }
}
```

The `make()` function accepts a function argument, and returns a new function.

The new function does whatever you want (in this case it just calls `console.log()`), then it calls the original function.

When it calls the original, it sets the current value of `this` and passes along the  `arguments`. It does this by invoking the function using `Function.prototype.apply`, which sets the `this` value from its first argument, and passes along arguments as a collection from its  second argument.

It also returns the value of whatever was returned from your function.

Answer (score 0):

http://jsfiddle.net/TUNQn/

```
var EntriesRegistry = (function(){

    var instance = null;

    function __constructor() {

        var
            self = this,
            observations = {};

        this.set = function(n,v)
        {
            self[n] = v;

            if( observations[n] )
                for( var i=0; i < observations[n].length; i++ )
                    observations[n][i].apply(null, [v, n]);

        }

        this.get = function(n)
        {
            return self[n];
        }

        this.observe = function(n,f)
        {

            if(observations[n] == undefined)
                observations[n] = [];

            observations[n].push(f);
        }

    }

    return new function(){
        this.getInstance = function(){
            if (instance == null)
            {
                instance = new __constructor();
                instance.constructor = null;
            }
            return instance;
        }
    }
})();

var entries = EntriesRegistry.getInstance();

var test = function(v){ console.log(entries); };
var name = function(person){
    alert("Hello " + person.first + " " + person.last);
}

/*entries.set('bob', 'meh');

entries.get('bob');*/

entries.observe('employer', name);
entries.observe('seth', test);

entries.set('seth', 'lo');
entries.set('employers', {first: 'test', last: 'test'});
```

This allows you to bind callbacks to object event changes

Answer (score -1):

There is no easy way to do it. If you had already written all of the 'original' methods and knew what the callback was called you could do what Felix mentioned in the comments and loop over each property on the object, and if it was a function, reassign it as a new function  that called the callback also:

```
for (key in obj) {

    if (typeof(key) === 'function') {
        obj[key] = function() {
            obj[key](); //I think this is closed over, didn't test though (might get clobbered)
            callback();
        }
    }
}
```

**EDITED** to change `key()` to `obj[key]()`

Comment: `key` is the **name** of the property and a string. You cannot call it.

Comment: `key` is a string, not a method.

Comment: Yes, you didn't test it. And `key` is a string. And you don't pass any arguments. And you're not returning anything.